# efficient algorithm to match a great number of strings against a fixed number of regex patterns

Tags: regex, performance, algorithm

## Context

When parsing web access logs, there is a need to separate bots from human user agents.

I built a list of them manually, extracted bot-like patterns (for instance containing **bot**). I have then a list of patterns (~300 items large) I validate incoming access logs against, real-time. Over time, this has become quite a bottleneck since my (inefficient) algorithm looks for any pattern; even if we ignore the performance drop that means a vulnerability to DoS.

## Code (java)

```
String userAgent;
List<Pattern> botPatterns;

    for (Pattern botPattern : botPatterns)
    {
        if (botPattern.matcher(userAgent).find())
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
```

## Already explored answers

#### using WURFL

This could be a simple solution but the results are sometimes inaccurate. Would like to avoid built-in solutions for now.

#### using a cache of user-agents

By storing user agent strings in a hashmap, it is possible to cache the results. However, even though this improves performance, this increases the vulnerability to a simple DoS attack with randomly-generated user agent strings.

## Question

Is there an efficient algorithm to match a great number (N) of strings against a fixed number of regex patterns (m) ?

## Edit : benchmarked answer

I benchmarked @stemm 's answer, with real-life data, and also with random-generated user agent strings. I ran the tests during 10s, and averaged the computing time.
The cache is a simple LFU ehcache of size 5000

Here are my results:

### pattern loop

#### no cache

real data : 101us

random data: 193us

#### with cache

real data : 4us

random data: 203us

### single pattern

#### no cache

real data : 100us

random data: 160us

#### with cache

real data : 3us

random data: 154us

## Conclusions

- For real-life situations, caching is the single most effective solution.
- Having a single pattern provides a 25% gain compared to looping over patterns.
- The cache is not as vulnerable to DoS as I thought it would be.

Thank you people for your answers and comments.

Comment: Why do you need _300_ patterns to determine if it's a bot or not?!

Comment: look at the links and the whole thread [why GNU grep is fast](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2010-August/019363.html). You could also consider it as [a spam problem](http://www.paulgraham.com/better.html).

Comment: @Lindrian There are a lot of variants, used by various crawlers and spiders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The main idea is to create gather pattern, which would contains all regexps you have.**

For example - you want find strings that matches any of these regexps: `^\d+$` or `^[aA]+$` or `^[a-z\s]+$`. So, you may combine them into such regex: `(^\d+$|^[aA]+$|^[a-z\s]+$)`

Sample java code:

```
public class Test {

    public static Pattern gather( String... patterns ) {
        StringBuilder finalRegexBuilder = new StringBuilder( "(" );
        for ( String ptr : patterns ) {
            finalRegexBuilder.append( ptr ).append( "|" );
        }
        finalRegexBuilder.setLength( finalRegexBuilder.length() - 1 );
        finalRegexBuilder.append( ")" );
        return Pattern.compile( finalRegexBuilder.toString() );
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Pattern regex = gather( "^\\d+$", "^[aA]+$", "^[a-z\\s]+$" );

        System.out.println( regex.toString() ); // (^\d+$|^[aA]+$|^[a-z\s]+$)

        System.out.println( regex.matcher( "1235" ).find() ); // true
        System.out.println( regex.matcher( "1235fdjg" ).find() ); // false
        System.out.println( regex.matcher( "AAAaaaAaa" ).find() ); // true
        System.out.println( regex.matcher( "hello world" ).find() ); // true
    }
}
```

*In fact - underlying mechanism of regex is a finite state machine. So, in code above we've got FSM that @mishadoff talked about.*

Answer (score 1):

If you have fixed number of patterns you can build [Finite State Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) to represent your patterns, that greatly improve performance. But this solution needs additional development for logic and representing FSM.

Example you have number of patterns [abc, abd, acd, dab]

Finite State Machine looks like:

```
start -> a -> b -> c -> finish
                -> d -> finish
           -> c -> d -> finish
      -> d -> a -> b -> finish
```

You can think about FSM like ordered graph with limited number of states. You want to match string `abd` on these patterns. Begin from start you encounter a -> b -> d and finish. Thta means that string matches that pattern that you can restore from path. More complex patterns with functionality like `*` and `?` you can represent with linking state to itself(`*`), or skipping this state at all (`?`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

In my case, this algorithm would require the generation of that Finite State Machine automatically from the patterns; this looks pretty hard...